# Failed to convert value of type Object to required type Object Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have two data Model User and Car :

**User.java :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="APP_USER")
public class User implements Serializable{

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
......

@OneToMany(mappedBy="user",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Car> cars = new HashSet<Car>();
```

**Car.java :**

```
@Entity
public class Car implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id ;
.....

@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name="user_fk")
private User user;
```

In the Controller , I want to add a new user , so

**AppController.java :**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
@SessionAttributes("roles")
public class AppController {

@RequestMapping(value = { "/newuser" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String newUser(ModelMap model) {
    User user = new User();
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    model.addAttribute("edit", false);
    model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
    return "registration";
}

@RequestMapping(value = { "/newuser" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveUser(@ModelAttribute @Valid User user, BindingResult result,
        ModelMap model) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "registration";
    }

    if(!userService.isUserSSOUnique(user.getId(), user.getSsoId())){
        FieldError ssoError =new FieldError("user","ssoId",messageSource.getMessage("non.unique.ssoId", new String[]{user.getSsoId()}, Locale.getDefault()));
        result.addError(ssoError);
        return "registration";
    }

    userService.saveUser(user);
    model.addAttribute("success", "User " + user.getFirstName() + " "+ user.getLastName() + " registered successfully");
    model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
    return "registrationsuccess";
}
```

Also , I created a class named StringToUser ( Implements Converter so I can add a new Car that contain a user )

**StringtoUser.java :**

```
@Autowired
UserService userService ;

@Override
public User convert(Object element) {
    Integer id = Integer.parseInt((String)element);
    User user = userService.findById(id);
    return user;
}
```

The AppController.java and saveUser method works fine before I add the StringToUser class .But after I created StringToUser class ,I get an error in saveUser method

```
The error is : WARNING: Failed to bind request element: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type [com.websystique.springmvc.model.User] to required type [com.websystique.springmvc.model.User]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [com.websystique.springmvc.model.User] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute @javax.validation.Valid com.websystique.springmvc.model.User] for value 'User [id=null, ssoId=alaa, password=alaa1991, firstName=, lastName=, email=, userProfiles=null, accounts=null, userDocuments=[], cars=[], documents=[]]'; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.websystique.springmvc.model.User cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Edit :

The error :

```
WARNING: Failed to bind request element: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type [com.websystique.springmvc.model.User] to required type [com.websystique.springmvc.model.User]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [com.websystique.springmvc.model.User] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute @javax.validation.Valid com.websystique.springmvc.model.User] for value 'User [id=null, ssoId=alaa, password=alaa1991, firstName=, lastName=, email=, userProfiles=null, accounts=null, userDocuments=[], cars=[], documents=[]]'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: It seems that your convert class is receiving a reference to User class instead the String representation you need. Have you tried replacing: Integer id = Integer.parseInt((String)element); for: Integer id = ((User)element).getId();

Comment: I just tried you example , I get the same problem !!

Comment: Can you provide the full error stack trace? Are you sure it is erroring out in the converter class?

Comment: I just added the error , please see below (there is a NullPointerException

Comment: @CristianColoradoCervantes Can you help me please ?! I can't find solution

Comment: Can you share your code implementation in github so i can review in detail?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use a converter, spring itself format your form into a *User* class.

If you debug your converter class, you will notice you do not receive a String as a parameter, you receive a reference to an instance of class *User*. So you are converting a User to a User which does not make sense.

```
@Override
    public User convert(Object element) {
        if (element == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        Integer id = ((User)element).getId();
        User user = userService.findById(id);
        return user;
    }
```

Now since you are trying to create a new User, your form does not set and ID, therefore you are providing *userService* a null. Your service fails and your converter fails showing you that error.

Easy solution is just remove it.

I understand you adding the roles converter, since the form is sending you a list of integers, that can not be parsed by spring into a Set. I would strongly recommend you to implement Command Objects as an intermediary to your model, that way you can avoid using a Set.

But if you need to implement a converter i would suggest below changes:

```
@Component
public class RoleToUserProfileConverter implements Converter<Object, UserProfile>{

    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RoleToUserProfileConverter.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserProfileService userProfileService;


    private HashMap<Integer, UserProfile> userProfiles;

    /**
     * Gets UserProfile by Id
     * @see org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter#convert(java.lang.Object)
     */
    public UserProfile convert(Object element) {
        Integer id = Integer.parseInt((String)element);
        UserProfile profile = findUserProfile(id);
        logger.info("Profile : {}",profile);
        return profile;
    }

    private UserProfile findUserProfile(Integer id) {
        //First time loading profiles
        if(userProfiles == null) {
            userProfiles = new HashMap<>();
            List<UserProfile> userProfileList = userProfileService.findAll();
            for(UserProfile userProfile: userProfileList) {
                userProfiles.put(userProfile.getId(), userProfile);
            }
        }
        if(userProfiles.containsKey(id)) {
            return userProfiles.get(id);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

In this example I use a hashmap to hold all UserProfiles which should change less, then those are loaded just the first time and retrived.

You could improve it by checking if the id you are looking is in the hash otherwhise query the database and store it, that way new UserProfiles are loaded on demand.

Comment: Hello @Cristian ,I just removed StringtoUser class and added findUserProfile method , I have tho same error , The user fom works fine , but the cars form not , the error is the same :

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute

Comment: Cristian , can I create those class without using converter to roles and user ?? I'm new in using spring , but in JSF we can do that without converter !!??